# UIViewActivityIndicator with NsurlConnection does not stop animation in swift

Tags: swift, ios8

I am calling `callDailyQuotes` methods on button click. The `activityIndicator` starts animating as data is downloaded from the server, but then the `activityIndicator` stops animating.

Here is the relevant code:

```
self.activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
   self.callDailyQuotes()
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in     
            })
        })

func callDailyQuotes(){
//calling nsurlconnection synchronously
 self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

What's happening that makes the `activityIndicator` stop animating?

Comment: Place the piece of code for stopping the activity indicator in main thread.

Comment: did u mean inside main queue?

Comment: Yes inside the main queue

Comment: I edited your question so that it begins with a problem statement. I turned your appeal for help into an actual question.  Good luck!

Comment: i tried it,but it is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to execute the `self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()` call in the main thread, so my suggestion is to move it in the `dispatch_async` you've already added but left empty:

```
self.activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
        let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
            self.callDailyQuotes()
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            })
        })

func callDailyQuotes(){
//calling nsurlconnection synchronously
}
```

Comment: actvityindicator does not animating

Comment: but in the question you said it starts animating, it just doesn't stop

Comment: then i changed my code as you suggested.now it is not start animating

Comment: I think it starts and stops so quickly that it is not visible. Do you have an actual implementation for `callDailyQuotes`? the indicator is stopped right after that is completed

Comment: yes.How do i make delay?so the indicator show for a while?

Comment: You can use `NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(5)` to make the thread sleep for 5 seconds